# Proper way to configuring docker network bridge on the host side

Tags: networking, docker, bridge, host

Edit: Note that I'm referring to a single host setup, some local server architecture and not some enterprise-grade backend :D

---

`docker network create` with the bridge driver creates an actual bridge device on the host machine. I'm adding the host NIC into the bridge `eth0`  (to achieve something similar to virtual machines bridge mode).

As with any bridge, when that happens, host `eth0` configurations, do not apply anymore, rather the docker-created network bridge interface is applied.
While I can set IP address and subnet for the bridge via docker, I cannot configure other settings, such as routes for example, or other interface-specific settings.

In addition, upon initial configuration of the bridge by docker when issuing the commands remotely-over SSH, if the ip address of the docker-bridge is on the same subnet as `eth0` the SSH connection and any communication with the host stops working **PERMANENTLY**, this is due to the fact that there is a subnet-collision between `eth0` and docker `br-xxxxx`, While `eth0` is a member of the bridge.

Questions:

1. in non-docker situations, what are the best practices when creating a bridge and adding the "management" interface of the host, `eth0` to it? - This problem of conflicting subnets and route dismissal would occur on any linux-bridge, as the underlaying interface configuration is ignored.
2. How can the interface created by the `docker network create` can be configured permanently. I Can use the standard linux files to configure the network, but whenever I'd recreate the setup naming of the br- would differ, It doesn't sound like a reasonable way to do this
3. Lastly, I Think the best solution for my situations is if there would be a script, tool or daemon, that would copy the existing `eth0` configuration, over to the new bridge, something that is manageable.

Thank you.

P.S1. I said `PERMANENTLY` above since docker bridges persists on boot, if static ip was configured by `dhcpcd` and there you have it, 2 interfaces with the same subnets on boot, hence, communication issues with the host (with respect to the `eth0` that work properly before adding it to the bridge)

P.S2. Please, don't ask why I'm joining the host if and the virtual one, a very odd and convenient use-case

Answer (score 1):

1. Depends, if each node is physical machine, then you need a physical router. You can also define multiple node for each machine as example:

```
(Network with 192.168.1.0/24 subnet)
- Machine #1
  - Node 1: 192.168.1.1
  - Node 2: 192.168.1.2
- Machine #2
  - Node 3: 192.168.1.3
  - Node 4: 192.168.1.4
```

With each machine has one bridge configured. But how to expose those IP address to local network? here's [the clue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25036895/how-to-expose-docker-containers-ip-and-port-to-outside-docker-host-without-port).

2. Use [docker-compose.yml](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rFQqiuFIjms) solution. Then use `docker-compose up` command to start configuration and `docker-compose down` to stop it.
3. Again, use [docker-compose.yml](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rFQqiuFIjms). Here is the [detail documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network-configuration-reference) for configuring network via docker compose.

Let me know if I missed something. Hope it helps, good luck!

Comment: Thanks, But I don't really make much out of your answer, my question might as well be regarding just a standard linux bridge without all the docker stuff; It's slightly different since on reboot the setting does not revert in `docker network create` with the bridge driver, as oppose to `brctrl addbr` or equivlent.